# citations : surname and year

Tags: citing

I use `biblatex` and would like the citations in the text to look like this:

> Einstein showed already in 1905 [Einstein 1905] .

for example I use the style `\usepackage[style = alphabetic-verb]{biblatex}`  so I see then

> Einstein showed already in 1905 [Ein05] .

but I would like to have the name and the year in the text fully written and in brackets.

Do you know the required style?

EDIT:

```
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{Projektarbeit.bib}
```

if I now quote something in the text - e.g.

```
Bernstein showed in \cite{Bernstein} , then I get
```

> Bernstein showed in [Ber02]

but, I would like to have:

> Bernstein showed  in [Berstein 1902].

is there a style that does exactly this, or do I have to create it myself?

Comment: you want an author year style.

Comment: yes but I don't know exactly which specifications, because if I take authoryear, then the whole author is written out in the text

Comment: Provide a full example that can be used to test your issue.

Comment: should i upload my bib file here? because otherwise i cannot create a reproducible example... at least - I have edited the question above and I believe that now it is clear what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) [says in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/563666/citations-surname-and-year#comment1420591_563666) this is more of an author-year style than an alphabetic style. An `alphabetic` style uses short alphabetic labels usually derived from the author and publication year to identify your entries. Usually an alphabetic style does not use the full name and year.

If you can use styles of the [`biblatex-ext` bundle](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext) (disclaimer: I'm the author of that style bundle), you can use `\DeclareOuterCiteDelims` to obtain square brackets.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{parencite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}
\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{textcite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{nussbaum}
dolor \autocite{worman}

\Citeauthor{worman} showed that blub \autocite{worman}.

\Textcite{nussbaum} proved \dots

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem [Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998] ipsum [Nussbaum 1978] dolor [Worman 2002]//Worman showed that blub [Worman 2002].//Nussbaum [1978] proved ...]

Comment: dear @moewe ! thank you!! fantastic =)